# case study for CTA text for blog

Tags: buttons, call-to-action, blog

I have a tech blog , and above the fold there will be a hero layout , with some title and tag lines which are important to the blog.

Below these  I have a CTA button , that will scroll to the second fold , where the articles start.

Right now I'm using the text for CTA as `start reading` . Which seems very boring to me.

Are there any case studies available , for the effectiveness of text on a blog CTA button ?

Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

CTAs have to be descriptive enough so users can guess where they will be taken to just by reading the label.

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/learn-more-links/

In you case, "Start Reading" seems reasonably descriptive. Maybe your blog has a theme or voice to it that can infuse some jazz to that CTA.